# How to get the whole line of text that contain a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

There's one thing that I want to ask. How can I get the whole line of text that contain a string in Visual Basic 2010?

Let's say:

MyText.txt file contains:

```
Configurations: 
Name: Fariz Luqman
Age: 78
My Favourite Fruit: Lemon, Apple, Banana
My IPv4 Address: 10.6.0.5
My Car: Ferrari
```

In Visual Basic, I want to get the whole line of text that contain the string "**Banana**" and print it in the textbox so it will display in that textbox:

```
My Favourite Fruit: Lemon, Apple, Banana
```

Why am I doing this? Because the text file is being appended and the line number is random. The contents is also random because the texts is generated by Visual Basic. The text "Banana" can be in line 1, line 2 or can be in any line so how can I get the whole line of text that contain certain string?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: My VB.Net is rusty, but C# has a Contains() method. Check to see if VB.Net has something similar. Then you could loop through the lines and use the appropriate method.

    IF linex.Contains("Banana"))
       //THEN do something to that line

Comment: Indeed! But I love visual basic in term of simplicity, and my lovely project is 98% nearly finished!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily all in one line with LINQ:

```
TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllLines("MyText.txt").FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("Banana"))
```

However, if the file is rather large, that's not particularly efficient, since it will read the whole file into memory before searching for the line.  If you want to make it stop loading the file once it finds the line, could use the `StreamReader`, like this:

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("Test.txt")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.Contains("Banana") Then
            TextBox1.Text = line
            Exit While
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! It have error "StreamReader is now defined" but fixing Using reader As New StreamReader("Test.txt") to Using reader As New **IO**.StreamReader("Test.txt") works! :D

Comment: Yes, my example assumes that you have the line `Imports System.IO` at the top of your code file.  Usually people leave out the namespaces in their examples on this site, for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Just checked (should have done that first!). VB.Net does have a CONTAINS() method. So:

```
IF line1.Contains("Banana") THEN
   'do something
END IF
```

Comment: So I can use it on my other controls also! Thanks mate for the answer!

Comment: I'm actually not a mate, I guess I'm a matette? :)  Anyway, glad you found my answer useful.

Comment: Cool! I just know that I can use it on other controls like textbox, eg "If txtStatus.Text.Contains("") Then ....". If I have 15 rep I would vote up already xD have a nice day, thanks for taking time to answer :)